# Merge Images Side by Side (Horizontally)

Tags: imagemagick

I have five images of sizes: 600x30, 600x30, 600x30, 600x30, 810x30. Their names are: 0.png, 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png, respectively.

How do I merge them Horizontally to make an image of size 3210x30 with ImageMagick?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

ImageMagick ships with the `montage` utility. Montage will append each image side-by-side allowing you to adjust spacing between each image (`-geometry`), and the general layout (`-tile`).

```sh
montage [0-4].png -tile 5x1 -geometry +0+0 out.png
```

Other examples can be found on [Montage Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) page

Comment: montage documentation specifies that the [0-5] syntax is for linux, so I guess if you are on windows you have to type/generate all the file names. i.e. montage 0.png 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png ...

Comment: @RodrigoGraça See [Usage & Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) guide about handling transparency + backgrounds.

Comment: it works for combination of jpg and png as well. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the bracket tip! Been using linux for years and only found `{0..4}`. See the "Ranges" section of the [glob manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) for documentation.

Comment: Following your lead, this worked perfectly to combine 2 jpegs side-by-side!: `montage left.jpg right.jpg -tile 2x1 -geometry +0+0 out.jpg`

Comment: You might want to add `-background none` to preserve transparency.

Answer (score 134):

ImageMagick has command line tool named '[convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)' to merge images horizontally, or for other purpose. i have tried this command and working perfectly on your case:

To join images horizontally:
`convert +append *.png out.png`

To stack images vertically:
`convert -append *.png out.png`

Comment: that can be added to a Thunar custom action in this form (ex. to join vertically = up-town):`convert -append %F joined-image.png` . All selected images will be joined as one png in alphabetical order

Comment: If using ImageMagick 7+ you'll need to put the images you're working on before the parameters: `convert *.png +append out.png`

Comment: To make a grid 2x2 (a.png, b.png, c.png, d.png):
`convert a.png b.png +append row1.png; convert c.png d.png +append row2.png; convert row1.png row2.png -append grid.png`

Answer (score 27):

**Use `-resize` if the images don't have the same width/height**

You can fix the height for all of them with the `-resize` option, e.g. to fix a 500 pixel height on two images joined horizontally:

```
convert +append image_1.png image_2.png -resize x500 new_image_conbined.png
```

Or for vertical joins, you would want to set a fixed width instead:

```
convert -append image_1.png image_2.png -resize 500x new_image_conbined.png
```

Example:

image_1.png 1067x600

[image]

image_2.png 1920x1080

[image]

new_image_conbined.png 889x500

[image]

Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/226054/how-do-i-join-two-images-together
- https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick

**How to do it interactively with GIMP**

If you need to crop/resize images interactively first, which is often the case, then GIMP is the perfect tool for it, here's a detailed step-by-step: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83446/gimp-how-to-combine-two-images-side-by-side/145543#145543

[image]

**SVGs**

ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 doesn't handle them, so see:

- [How to concatenate SVG files lengthwise from linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612434/how-to-concatenate-svg-files-lengthwise-from-linux-command-line)
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137096/is-there-a-way-to-stack-two-svgs-on-top-of-each-other
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90844/joining-together-multiple-svg-images

Comment: This one should be the chosen answer. montage is overkill.

Comment: What if I want to resize the bigger image to smaller image's size automatically? (so that I don't have to explicitly pass its height)

Answer (score 12):

Very simple with ImageMagick (`brew install imagemagick` )

```
convert +append image_1.png image_2.png new_image_conbined.png
```

Comment: Nice... Copy an existing answer, get +10 votes.

Comment: When I run this, for some reason, one of my images end up being rotated. So for example, imagine I'm trying to stack V on top of E. Instead of getting:

V
E

I get something that looks like:

^
E

(I'm using the '-append' option)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using the `MiniMagick` rails gem can use the built-in tool to merge images:

```
# Replace this with the path to the images you want to combine
images = [
  "image1.jpg",
  "image2.jpg"
]

processed_image = MiniMagick::Tool::Montage.new do |image|
  image.geometry "x700+0+0"
  image.tile "#{images.size}x1"
  images.each {|i| image << i}
  image << "output.jpg"
end
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) for `#geometry` options to handle resizing and placement. The current example will resize images to a `700px` height while maintaining the image's aspect ratio. `+0+0` will place the image with no gaps between them.

Answer (score 1):

The `convert +append` method described in other answers appends images horizontally, aligned to the top. If you prefer to align to the bottom or center, try:

```
convert input1.png input2.png -gravity South +append output.png
  or
convert input1.png input2.png -gravity Center +append output.png
```

Source: Fred's ImageMagick Tidbits http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tidbits/image.php#append

Comment: Nice! Of course use `-gravity North` to align to the top.